# I have a problem about updating system

Tags: updates

when I try to update my elementary Loki from terminal I found this thing I don't know What is it mean

```
W: http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick/InRelease: Signature by key 630239CC130E1A7FD81A27B140976EAF437D05B5 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
```

I don't know how to fix it so anyone can help I will be so happy

Answer (score 2):

**This line is basically a warning about old software.** *There are no pieces of software or software repositories that will be removed after an update with this warning.*

Most likely you have a PPA / other software repository that uses an ancient digest algorithm but you cannot fix it locally, you have to contact the owner of the repository. In this case, Ubuntu maverick was a release about 6 years ago, so there is not much chance that this warning gets fixed.

However, if security is not your primary concern (as in using 6 years old software repository / distribution…) you can ignore this warning.

Comment: so it's not gonna be remove this PPA from repository I just can ignore this warning